# Function Context in Javascript and this Keyword

Tags: javascript

Could somebody here please get this straight for all of us once and for all?

```
var parent = {child: function(){
        console.log(this); 
        var log = function(){ 
        console.log(this);}; 
        log();
    }
}
```

When I call `parent.child()`
I get:

```
Object{}
Window{}
```

Other people/ documentation on Mozilla say that this function has been invoked without any context. And

```
this
```

will be the object on which the function is invoked. 
What I don't understand is how on earth this function within another object is considered to be without a context(so `this` defaulted to the global object). What's the logic here? Thanks

Comment: `log` is called without context. If you want to call it with context, you should do `log.call(this)`. Without context you get `window` in sloppy mode, `undefined` in strict mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Thanks. I know that. What I wondering is how it is called without a context.

Comment: Because there is no object/property relation involved, like `object.log()`, but just `log()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function referenced at objects are like methods. When you directly call a function by indexing an object, this same object will be referenced by `this` in the scope the function will generate.

When calling a function without indexing an object, or without setting `this` context (with `apply`, `bind`, `call`, ...), if it's not at strict mode (or is at least in a global scope when at strict mode) `this` should be the global object.

When objects are instances of classes/interfaces/functions, their methods also capture this same object for `this`.

This is how it works for me:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    console.log(this) // undefined
})()

console.log(this) // Window{}
```